# Custom UINavigationItem in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uinavigationitem

I have a question about UINavigationItem..

I have crete a project with a storyboard and I have add a NavigationController as first controller of this.

I have add also a TabBarController with some ViewController..

Now, I would to add a button on NavigationItem of a my ViewController like you can see into this screenshot:

[image]

But, when I run my application I not see this my custom NavigationItem...I not see this right button...

I not have customized this NavigationItem programmatically.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Each tab bar item should have its own navigation controller.

Comment: May be your tint colour for navigation bar also green?